# restoring a table from sql file in postgresql through Windows Command prompt

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to restore an sql file which contains the dumpf a table (with COPY commands) into a table into the database, it would be great if someone could share an example, as the pg_restore doesn't help much in this regard. A link would do as well.

Further information: Through the psql command line client I tried to first access the database and then execute the method presented by @a_horse _with_no_name; but nothing seemed to happen, it just went on to show the next prompt; but there was no change in the backend(data was not inserted into the database). I may be doing something grossly wrong here, just got started with PostgreSQL. :)

Comment: What kind of *dumpf" ? is it readable?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name- A step by step of what I did.
1.Windows command line prompt 
2. Changed to the bin folder of Postgresql.
3. placed the dump (sql file) in the bin folder.
4.Executed psql  dbname<dumpfile.sql.
Would be great if you could tell me what Im doing wrong, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your dump file contains COPY statements, then it's a SQL dump which is restored using `psql` as [explained in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE).

```
psql dbname < your_dump_file.sql
```

More examples are in the manual.

Comment: tried that!(Nothing happened) In this case my dump file just contains one table, so _should_ a new table be created then?

Comment: You should have included that information (that you already tried psql) into your original question. I don't believe that "*nothing happened*" - please edit your question to include the exact statements you used (e.g. copy & paste the text from the console)